# Overwrite or Overload a node_module name path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management, package.json

Assume i have a installed node_module called `magicalModule` and I have installed it via `npm i magicalModule`.

I import it into my code via `const magic = require('magicalModule')`.

Is there a way for me to overwrite that specific path so that I can use my own module instead?

For example I have a modified version of that module that I want to use instead of the installed package. Maybe place something in package.json or something like:

```
dependencies:{
    Alias:{
         'magicalModule': process.env.local ? './myPath' : 'magicalModule'
    }
}
```

Something like above...

I know that there is a module called [Module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) but I'm not sure if it fits my use case.

As to why I would need to do something like this is because there is an NPM package that is used alot in multiple files and I want to replace it with another NPM package that I'm currently developing. Wanna test it locally before publishing that NPM package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, after some tinkering the solution was to use [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) after all.
In my main file I added to the top of it before any code:

```
if(process.env.useLocal) require('module-alias/register')
```

Then in my package.json file I added:

```
 "_moduleAliases": { "magicalModule" : "path_to_file" }
```

after my dependencies section, it overwrites path to node_modules and my project will use my local module instead.

Hope this helps anyone else out there who needs to do something similar to me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you need dynamic import then put require in an if condition

```
let myModule = require(process.env.local ? './myPath' : 'myModule'); // make sure there is index.js inside
```

You **cannot do it in package.json** as that file is static. However if you can somehow edit package json then **local dependencies can be added** like

```
"dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:./myPath" // package.json is read inside of ./myPath
  }
```

Comment: The problem with ur suggestion on the if condition is that i would have to do it for over 50 plus files.... which is not a good sign i think. I would most likely do that if no better solution can be found